# Using the same Embedding for Encoder and Decoder in seq2seq

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building an translation-machine based on the the seq2seq-class. The class assumes different vocabularies for the encoder and the decoder part. Thus also it expects different embeddings for the two.

However, I am trying to use this inside a single language. Thus I would like the two embeddings to be one. (Background is to translate laymen's terms to experts' terms, inside the same language)

Currently the relevant code is:

Encoder-Side:
in python/ops/rnn_cell.py in EmbeddingWrapper():

```
with vs.variable_scope(scope or "EmbeddingWrapper"):
        additional_info_size   with vs.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):
      with ops.device("/cpu:0"):
        embedding = vs.get_variable("embedding", [self._embedding_classes, self._embedding_size], initializer=initializer)
        embedded = embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(embedding, array_ops.reshape(inputs, [-1]))
```

Decoder-Side:
In python/ops/seq2seq.py in embedding_rnn_decoder():

```
  with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope or "embedding_rnn_decoder"):
    with ops.device("/cpu:0"):
      embedding = variable_scope.get_variable("embedding", [num_symbols, embedding_size])
    loop_function = _extract_sksk_argmax_and_embed(
        embedding, output_projection,
        update_embedding_for_previous) if feed_previous else None
    emb_inp = (embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(embedding, i) for i in decoder_inputs)
```

Any idea how to elegantly get those two to use the same embedding-matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reusing variable scope when you call the function which creates the second embedding. If you use a scope with the same name and set reuse=True the embedding will be reused. The documentation on [sharing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) is relevant.

Comment: Thought so. In order to do that I'll have to pull the creation of the embedding variable up from relatively deep in the system to a higher or change the scopes deep down in the ops.